# Can I Move fields in a Crystal Report to another position when run?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating an invoice for various clients.  Some clients have a sales allowance.  For those clients I want to display an extra sales allowance unit and total cost column.

If any maximum sales cost total is = 0 I want to move the fields to the left and display the sales allowance on the right side

**When the client has sales allowance**

```
------------------Headings extend all the way across the report-----------------------------

Description   Qty    UOW      Client Unit Cost   Client Cost    Sales Unit Cost   Sales Cost
============================================================================================
Something       5   Each                $11.00        $55.00              $5.00       $25.00
More Stuff      2   Each                $20.00        $40.00              $5.00       $10.00
============================================================================================
Totals                                                $55.00                          $35.00
```

**When the client does not have sales allowance**

```
------------------Headings extend all the way across the report-----------------------------

Description                                   Qty    UOW      Client Unit Cost   Client Cost
============================================================================================
Something                                       5   Each                $11.00        $55.00
More Stuff                                      2   Each                $20.00        $40.00
============================================================================================
Totals                                                                                $95.00
```

The goal is to put this functionality into a single report rather than having to know which report to run for which client if and when they get a sales allowance.

I know we can supress fields and when I tried to incorporate that I got whitespace on either the right of middle depending on where I placed the fields and the result was not acceptable.  Is there a way to move a field to a different LEFT position when conditions are met?  This would be report wide, not evalutated on each detail record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier if you create two header sections and two detail sections with the fields and headers that you want in each.  Suppress the relevant header/detail section based on the presence of a value in the sales-allowance field (Isnull({table.sales_allowance}).  If this can't be determined, use a parameter field to drive the suppression formulae.

** edit **

the report will have two header sections (HA & HB) and two detail sections (DA & DB).  HA & DA work in combination, as do HB & DB.  Use the 'A' set for customers with a sales allowance; use the 'B' set for customers without.  Add the relevant fields to each section and header; *space accordingly*.

Set the suppression formula for HA & DA to:

```
//suppress section if there IS NOT a sales allowance
Not(Isnull({table.sales_allowance}))
```

Set the suppression formula for HB & DB to:

```
//suppress section if there IS a sales allowance
Isnull({table.sales_allowance})
```

**You do NOT need to suppress any individual fields with this approach, thus eliminating the spacing issue.**

** edit ** 
while crystal report objects do have X (left), Y (top), width, and height properties, only X and width support conditional formulae (CF).  you could move a field by setting the conditional formula of a field's X property to another value.

this approach would be harder to maintain, however.  each field's CF would need to 'remember' two positions: visible and hidden.  moreover, if another field was added in the future, each 'moveable' field would need to be reviewed to ensure that the positioning in its CF is accurate.

Comment: I was hoping to learn if you had the capability to move fields but this is a viable solution.