# Moving fields in crystal reports section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report having 4 fields.
    Whenever 1st 2 fields are null i need to move the  remaining 2 fields to first 2 fields   place.Is it possible.please suggest

Comment: do you also want to move column headers?

Comment: Hi Pratik Yes i need to move

Comment: I think this will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681959/can-i-move-fields-in-a-crystal-report-to-another-position-when-run

Comment: Hi Prathik Thanks but That is not my requirement

Comment: Can you draw the format to represent the requirement? It will help understand the requirement. thanks

Comment: Hi suppose my report is like this                                                        Empname     city      Region         country                                 if Empname and city is null then i need to show like this                         Region     country

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38103/discussion-between-vissubabu-and-pratik-kaje)

Comment: At work. Chat is disabled here.

Comment: I have an idea, but first, I have a couple questions. Is your data in a header, detail, or footer section? Is it just data or do you have summaries or other formulas included in those sections? A mockup or screenshot would also help (but not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Place the fields one above the other and write the supress condition as per your requiewment.